# How can make the character to rotate according to the camera rotation angle?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This is the script i'm using attached to the Main Camera.
I can rotate the camera 360 degrees. But the character(ThirdPersonController) is keep standing idle facing same position all the time.

I want to make that when i rotate the camera that also the character will rotate.

And a problem i have is i can rotate the came to the ground level a bit under it.
How can i limit the camera rotation to the ground/terrain level ?
This is a screenshot what i mean the camera is under the terrain/character:

[image: Screenshot]

And this is the script code:
I tried to add this line to rotate the character with the camera but it's not doing it, it does nothing.

```
transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.rotation, rotation, rotationSpeed);
```

The script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

[AddComponentMenu("Camera-Control/Mouse Orbit with zoom")]
public class MouseOrbitImproved : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Transform target;
    public float distance = 5.0f;
    public float xSpeed = 120.0f;
    public float ySpeed = 120.0f;

    public float yMinLimit = -20f;
    public float yMaxLimit = 80f;

    public float distanceMin = .5f;
    public float distanceMax = 15f;

    private Rigidbody rigidbody;

    float x = 0.0f;
    float y = 0.0f;

    public float rotationSpeed = 5f;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        Vector3 angles = transform.eulerAngles;
        x = angles.y;
        y = angles.x;

        rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

        // Make the rigid body not change rotation
        if (rigidbody != null)
        {
            rigidbody.freezeRotation = true;
        }
    }

    void LateUpdate()
    {
        if (target)
        {
            x += Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * xSpeed * distance * 0.02f;
            y -= Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * ySpeed * 0.02f;

            y = ClampAngle(y, yMinLimit, yMaxLimit);

            Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.Euler(y, x, 0);

            distance = Mathf.Clamp(distance - Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel") * 5, distanceMin, distanceMax);

            RaycastHit hit;
            if (Physics.Linecast(target.position, transform.position, out hit))
            {
                distance -= hit.distance;
            }
            Vector3 negDistance = new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, -distance);
            Vector3 position = rotation * negDistance + target.position;

            transform.rotation = rotation;
            transform.position = position;

            transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.rotation, rotation, rotationSpeed);
        }
    }

    public static float ClampAngle(float angle, float min, float max)
    {
        if (angle < -360F)
            angle += 360F;
        if (angle > 360F)
            angle -= 360F;
        return Mathf.Clamp(angle, min, max);
    }
}
```

I created a new small clean script that should rotate the character according to the camera rotation. The above script is attached to the Main Camera.

Now i have the ThirdPersonController and i have a script already attached to it:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ClickToMove : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int speed = 5; // Determines how quickly object moves towards position
    public float rotationSpeed = 5f;

    private Vector3 targetPosition;
    private Animator _animator;
    private Vector3 destination;
    private Quaternion targetRotation;

    void Start()
    {
        _animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
        _animator.CrossFade("Idle", 0);
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Mouse0))
        {
            _animator.CrossFade("Walk", 0);
            Plane playerPlane = new Plane(Vector3.up, transform.position);
            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
            float hitdist = 0.0f;

            if (playerPlane.Raycast(ray, out hitdist))
            {
                Vector3 targetPoint = ray.GetPoint(hitdist);
                targetPosition = ray.GetPoint(hitdist);
                targetRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(targetPoint - transform.position);
                destination = targetPosition;
            }
        }

        transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.rotation, targetRotation, rotationSpeed);

        if ((transform.position - destination).magnitude < 0.7f)
        {
            _animator.CrossFade("Idle", 0);
        }
    }
}
```

This script is working fine. Also the script above that rotate the camera.
But once i attach to the ThirdPersonController the new small script that should rotate the character so first it's not rotating the character and second it's making the character to walk on forward the whole ClickToMove script is not working good.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class RotateCharacterToCamera : MonoBehaviour {

    void Update () {

        Vector3 characterPosition = transform.position;
        Vector3 cameraPosition = Camera.main.transform.position;
        Vector3 delta = new Vector3(characterPosition.x - characterPosition.x, 0.0f, characterPosition.z - characterPosition.z);
        transform.LookAt(delta);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess simply adjusting the **yMinLimit** value to *0* or less should be enough to limit your camera vertical angle.

About your character rotation, you should have a small script on him that calls something like :

```
Vector3 characterPosition = transform.position;
Vector3 cameraPosition = Camera.main.transform.position;
Vector3 delta = new Vector3(characterPosition.x - characterPosition.x, 0.0f, characterPosition.z - characterPosition.z);
transform.LookAt(delta);
```

I set the *y* value of **delta** vector to 0 so only the "horizontal" orientation of the camera will be considered.

Comment: I don't have camera.Main there is no Main property on camera. I tried to make a variable i did Camera _camera then i did in Start function _camera getcomponent but then if i make _camera. i also don't have Main. So i changed the camera.Main only to _camera.transform and i attached the script to my ThirdPersonCharacter and dragged the Main Camera to this script in the inspector but i'm null exception say no camera attached to the ThirdPersonController but trying to access camera.

Comment: I also updated my question with the camera script problem. If i dragged the camera to the script why it's null ?

Comment: @mosheralf My bad I made a typo : it was supposed to be `Camera.main` instead of `camera.Main` (this allows you to access your main camera easily). But if you use a public _Camera_ field you don't need the line in the _Start()_ method anymore : if you call `_camera = GetComponent<Camera>();`, you override the _Camera_ field you assigned in the inspector with a `null ` Object (causing the error you got).

Comment: Ok now i don't have the exception. But another problem. When i attach this new small script to the character it's not rotating the character with the camera and it's not let me make the point and click with the script i already have attached to it.  I will show the script.

Comment: Updated my question with the new camera script and the script i already have attached to the ThirdPersonController.

Comment: The problem I see now is you have 2 scripts trying to adjust your player orientation : on the one hand the **ClickToMove** that should rotate the player towards it's target destination and on the other hand, the small piece of script that "align" the player with the _Camera_. Here, you'll have to choose how you want to rotate your player : with the _Camera_ or by clicking the floor ?

Comment: What i want to do is if the character is on "Idle" i will be able to rotate the camera and the character. Once i clicked the mouse and the character is in "Walk" state i will be able only to rotate the camera the player will keep walking to the mouse position.  Once he reached the mouse clicked position again i will be able to rotate the camera and the player untill i will click the mouse again. The camera rotation should be any time but the character rotation with the camera should be only on Idle.

Comment: @mosheralf In this case you have to make your scripts communicate or to use a kind of manager class that will handle when which script can or can't modify your player's rotation.